# Supervisor doesn't recognize environment variable in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, supervisord

This is my supervisor setting for a NodeJS API, but the `NODE_ENV` variable doesn't get recognized. API works in Default mode right now. But I want it to run it in NODE_ENV development

```
[program:api]
command=/usr/bin/node /srv/apps/api/src/index.js
directory=/srv/apps/api
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stderr_logfile=/srv/logs/api/error.log
stdout_logfile=/srv/logs/api/out.log
user=api-user
environment= NODE_ENV="development"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that after typing `supervisorctl reread` you should also use `supervisorctl update`